# Delegate method when Deleting or Offload App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a delegate method in iOS when application is about to be delete or Offload the App?i'm trying to send a some data to server

Required the above delegate method to help the user when they install the app on same iPhone given an message 
example : "Welcome Back"

Comment: Do you mean jettison from the suspended state or do you mean when the user deletes the app (or iOS offloads it after not being used for some time)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for quick response but terminate method won't call when delete  or Offload the app.

Comment: No, there is no apis to identify the deletion of the app.

Answer (score 3):

**NO**, there is no such delegate method/event/API that you can trigger whenever the app gets delete or offload.